# How can I make a cell with a fixed width in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

My question is quite simple, but I wonder if it's possible to do that with `GridBagLayout`. Note it might be easier with another layout but my goal is to do it that way.

So basically I wonder if there is a way to have a column with a **fixed width**? (so if I put inside this cell a long or a short label, it won't change its width)

Comment: I don't think so, the size of any given column is determined either by the size of the components in it or the results of the constraints, which can vary

Comment: Put the JLabel inside of a JPanel using a FlowLayout.  Set the preferred size of the (JLabel) JPanel.  Put the JPanel inside of the JPanel with the GridBagLayout.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Thanx but honestly it doesn't work that well, because `setPreferredSize()` method needs information about the height, which I don't have when calling it. And the behaviour is not very solid, when the window is resized (diminished), the size changes and doesn't fit the provided data any more. I guess `setPreferredSize()` is not such a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override the `GridBagLayout's` method

```
protected GridBagLayoutInfo GetLayoutInfo(Container parent, int sizeflag)
```

Just call super and change `public int columnWidths[]` array field updating desired width.

Comment: +1, never thought about going that deep in a `Layout`. Interesting approach :-)

Comment: Hi, thanx for the trick, but I didn't manage to do what you suggested. I know you might find it annoying, but could you please provide a concrete piece of code that implements your solution. I tried, but I have an error message...